# file_detector error watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I need to upload file through file field form. Locally it works fine. But through Selenium Grid test need to upload file to remote machine.

The solution is using file detector. As described here https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/175 or here https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload

In my hooks.rb

```
require "watir-webdriver"

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new

capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(browser_name: ENV['BROWSER'].to_sym, :http_client => client)
browser = if ENV['REMOTE']
  Watir::Browser.new(
    :remote,
    url: 'http://remoteurl:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities: capabilities,
    :http_client => client
  )
else
  Watir::Browser.new(ENV['BROWSER'].to_sym, :http_client => client)
end

browser.driver.file_detector = lambda do |args|
  str = args.first.to_s
  str if File.exist?(str)
end
```

But when I run tests they end up with error:
`` undefined method `file_detector=' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x000000012902b0> (NoMethodError) ``

How can I upload file via Selenium Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the code, the `file_detector=` method is defined in the `Selenium::WebDriver::DriverExtensions::UploadFiles` module. The only bridge that uses this driver extension is the `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Bridge` class.

In other words, the method will only be available to browsers created using the `:remote` type:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote)
```

I assume your are getting this exception when using non-remote drivers (ie when going down the "else" part of the "if" statement). Try moving the setting of the file_detector to only be when using a remote driver.

```
if ENV['REMOTE']
  browser = Watir::Browser.new(
    :remote,
    url: 'http://remoteurl:4444/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities: capabilities,
    :http_client => client
  )
  browser.driver.file_detector = lambda do |args|
    str = args.first.to_s
    str if File.exist?(str)
  end  
else
  browser = Watir::Browser.new(ENV['BROWSER'].to_sym, :http_client => client)
end
```